# What is taking up space on my RAID 1 hard disk drive setup after formatting?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, disk-space, format, bitlocker

I have two new 2TB hard drives and I made RAID 1 and made a bitlocker for them

After format it reports there is 237 MB used I didn’t copy anything, I have turned off virtual memory and system restore.

Where does this used space coming from?

Also I have installed winhex and the same 237 MB used space and there is no files?

Only system volume information folder and `$RECYCLE.BIN` which doesn’t contain any thing?

Comment: the NTFS metadata also use some space.

Answer (score 0):

On any freshly formatted NTFS partition, there are several meta files in the root directory which are as follows:

```
$MFT  
$MFTMirr  
$LogFile  
$Volume  
$AttrDef  
$Bitmap  
$BadClus  
$Secure  
$UpCase  
$Extend\$Quota  
$Extend\$ObjId  
$Extend\Reparse
```

These files are hidden an cannot be seen or accessed even if you show hidden/system files.  They are part of the filesystem itself. These files take some space to store, their size being dependent on how big the drive is and how many files are on it.

It does not matter that the drives are in a RAID (that is handled by the RAID controller) or the fact that you’re using Bitlocker (Bitlocker demands its own partition).